# cglobal() behaves differently when used with a "my" or "our" variable

Tags: raku, nativecall

I found out something I cannot explain, so I golfed it to what I think is the bare minimum:

```
# file OurTest.rakumod
unit module OurTest;

use NativeCall;

our $our-errno is export := cglobal('libc.so.6', 'errno', int32); # note the "our"
```

```
# file test.raku
use NativeCall;
use lib '.';
use OurTest;

my $my-errno := cglobal('libc.so.6', 'errno', int32); # note the "my"

say $my-errno.^name;   # output: Int
say $our-errno.^name;  # output: Any
```

Why do the variables declared as `my` and `our` seem to contain different type of data?
No hint of that behavior in the documentation, this was unexpected to me.

Comment: Might it be to do with the fact the cglobal returns a Proxy?

Comment: Note in particular both "As explained, the issue here is not specific to export." and also "We certainly could warn that binding to an `our` variable is pointless use of `our`." in a comment on the answer of the SO this one duplicates.